# PhoneGap Support for Blackberries 6.0+

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I need to decide whether to use phonegap to create a blackberry application. The lure of the app being deployable to various platforms is enticing however I need to know if it will be able to support Blackberry versions 6.0+. So far the website claims support for 5.0, and 6.0. There is a link at: [PhoneGap Supported Versions](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494777/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20%28BlackBerry%29) that is meant to explain which ones are supported however one link doesn't work and another takes you to a dated stackoverflow thread. I get the same results from other searches.

My question is can phonegap support higher blackberry operating systems such as 7.0 and later developments by RIM? Also if stability in terms of not having to continuously modify the application for oncoming OSs was important, would it be better to use RIM's WebWorks SDK rather than PhoneGap?

Answer (score 6):

If you are only going to target RIM phones then the WebWorks SDK is probably the best way to go. If you want to target other devices that run iOS and Android then you should look at PhoneGap.

We get really good involvement from RIM on PhoneGap. They did all the code to add Playbook support to PhoneGap and are currently involved in the unified JS project as well.